# BEC in interacting systems

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

What is your thought on the following statement: "any system of (weak/ strong) interacting bosons, in liquid phase, will form a condensate at T=0". Any example or counter-example ? Will dimensionality play any role? Thanks!

Comment: Many counter examples. In one spatial dimension there is no spontaneous symmetry breaking at $T=0$. In two dimensions, interacting bosons in a lattice can form a Mott insulator.

Answer (score 1):

No, most bosonic atoms (all except H and He) form solids. In fact, most of the BECs studied experimentally with ultracold atomic gases are metastable. The true ground state is a solid.

Comment: Thanks! Probably I wanted ask about liquid phase, please see the edit.

Comment: Yes, but if you ask about T=0 then you are asking what kind of materials have a stable liquid phase at T=0. The answer is not many.